# MongoDB removing subdocument issue

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I'm trying to remove specific sub document by it's _id. In eventArrayModel there are plenty of documents.
I'm looking for match for origin of sub document by field *resource*. This is what i come up with, but it doesn't work. Any ideas ?

```
const removedPost = await eventArrayModel.update({resource: req.params.teamMember}, {$pull: { array : {_id: ObjectId("5ef0a884c09b8e9ff01c8007")}}});
```

[Structure of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PawfV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PawfV.png) you provided, the `resource` field is inside the `array` field. try changing the update query to:

```js
await eventArrayModel.update(
  {
    'array.resource': req.params.teamMember
  },
  { $pull: { array: { _id: ObjectId('5ef0a884c09b8e9ff01c8007') } } }
)
```